# How can I allow only specific users to use my repository?

Tags: apt

I have an apt repository server. Is there a way to allow only specific users / machines to connect to my repository? Through crednetials, certificates or any other way? It can't be IP or some other device agnostic parameter.

Thanks

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/111885/securely-restrict-access-to-a-private-debian-repository, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941517/how-to-access-local-apt-repository-that-requires-http-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First enable basic authentication on your web-server.

For apache, `conf-available/mysite.conf` may look like so:

```
<Directory "/var/www/apt/debian">
        AllowOverride None
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Request a token for access"
        AuthUserFile "/etc/htpasswd/.htpasswd"
        Require user master
</Directory>
```

See `man htpasswd` for instructions to generate the AuthUserFile.

Assuming `DocumentRoot /var/www/apt`, URL `http://example.org/debian` should now prompt you for a username/password.

Next, configure `apt` on each client to provide this authentication when doing an HTTP request to the server.  Details for how to do this are in `man apt_auth.conf`.  This can be done by issuing a "token" to the repository user.  That file should look something like this:

```
machine example.org
login master
password pass1234
```

or this:

```
machine example.org login master password pass1234
```

When you give this token to the user, have them install it into `/etc/apt/auth.conf.d/*.conf`

Comment: Do I have to configure basic auth for the server? Isn't configuring apt_auth.conf enough?

Comment: @jojo if you don't configure auth on the server how will it prevent anyone else accessing it.  That was the point of your question.

Comment: @PhilipCouling I thought apt has a separate auth mechanism.

Comment: Nope.  An `apt` repository is simply a file structure layout.  That could exist in a location on disk, on a cdrom, or over a network served via HTTP.  The HTTP serving is not part of `apt` itself and you can use anything to do that (`apache`, `nginx`, `flask`, or your own server).